# Unable to access strong parameters from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My kingdom for the answer to this stumper. My application is giving errors from the controller that it can't find a parameter that I'm passing from the view.  I looked more into the console and added some puts statements.  The view is passing the parameter values correctly and the parameters are both listed in strong parameters but controller can't find them.  Here is the code and console log output.

View

```
<%= form_for @order_item, class: "form-control", remote: false do |f| %>
<div class="artist-event-item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="artist-event-item-info col-sm-8">
            <h3>Ticket</h3>
            <ul class="row">
                <li class="col-sm-6">
                    <span>Venue</span>
                    <%= product.section.venue.address_street_number %> <%= product.section.venue.address_street_name %> 
                    <span class="location"><%= product.section.venue.address_city %>, <%= product.section.venue.address_state_code %></span>
                 </li>
                <li class="col-sm-6">
                    <span>Section</span>Section <%= product.section.name%> - <%=product.section.description %>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="artist-event-item-price col-sm-4">
            <span>Ticket Price</span>
            <strong><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>
            </strong>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-2 center">
                <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 0, min: 0, class: "select.form-group-sm    form-control" %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
                <%= f.button "Add to Cart", data: { remote: true, disable_with: "<i class = 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Updating cart..." }, class: "btn btn-add-to-cart" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
private

def set_product

  puts "quantity is #{params[:quantity]}"
  puts "product id is #{params[:product_id]}"
  @product = @account.products.find(params[:product_id])
end

def order_item_params
  params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id)
end
```

end

output from rails console

```
Started POST "/order_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-11 16:42:36 -0400
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "order_item"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"13"}, "button"=>""}
Account Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "[FILTERED]"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19
CACHE Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "[FILTERED]"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:23`

quantity is 
product id is 
Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product without an ID):
app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:51:in set_product'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to find a product here:

```
@product = @account.products.find(params[:product_id])
```

But as you can see, your params doesn't include `params[:product_id]`:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", 
  "order_item"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"13"}, 
  "button"=>""
}
```

You can do:

```
@product = @account.products.find(params[:order_item][:product_id])
```

If the `:product_id` in the `:order_item` param is the one you're looking for.

You could also do:

```
@product = @account.products.find(order_item_params[:product_id])
```

Comment: That was it..thank you @jvillian for the answer and cleaning up my question.